# VBS script which add some program to windows startup list

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I need VBS or CMD script which add startup program any windows version.
I am searching this script in google but there is no work example.

For Example:
I have program -> D:\test.exe
I want to run this when windows loaded.

I think it is possible with VBS or Batch script.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v Test /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "d:\Test.exe" /f
```

Type reg /? for Help.

From The Technical Reference to the Windows 2000 Registry, they didn't document HKCU, that's the per user one.

Run 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\

Description
The Run subkey of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software stores the names of programs that Windows 2000 runs at startup, for all users of the computer, each time the system starts.

Each entry in the subkey represents a program. The value of the entry is the name of the executable file for the program. These entries have the following format:

Program Name  REG_SZ  File name